# Where to build data source for display in a screen in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a screen in flutter `SearchFoodItemPage` It is a stateful widget in a file named `search_food_item_page.dart`.
My purpose is to fetch list of items from firebase and display it on this screen.
I want to fetch data from firebase when this screen starts. I want to do all the data fetching in this file.

For that I tried fetching data in `build` method of the the widget. But we cannot add async modifier to the build method hence it did not work. I would like to know where to build the data source for this purpose.

Below is the code snippet for this screen.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; // new
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; // new

class SearchFoodItemPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchFoodItemPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;



  @override
  _SearchFoodItemPageState createState() => _SearchFoodItemPageState();
}

class _SearchFoodItemPageState extends State<SearchFoodItemPage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<String> _adsList = [];
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// code for building data source
      print("****************************************************************************");
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('ads')
          .get()
          .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          print(doc["_iname"]);
          _adsList.add( doc["_iname"] as String );
        });
      });
      print('${_adsList.length}');
      for (final foodname in _adsList) {
        print('${foodname.toString()}');
      }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 





    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // AdvertisementForm(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `FutureBuilder` as shown in the FlutterFire documentation on [reading data using `get`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read) and the example of [using a `ListView`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes) in that same page:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ads').get(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Something went wrong");
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(data['_iname']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      }

      return Text("loading");
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing! I submitted edit for changing DocumentSnapshot to QuerySnapshot in first two occurances and removed "has data " check due to synatx error. Feel free to edit if it can be further improved. Thanks!